# Parse: How to get user to sign up with phone Number?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I don't want the user to sign up with username, email, password. I just want the user to have a username and phoneNumber that it checks with verification via SMS. How do I go about doing this?

If I were to use just username and password for signup it would look like this:

```
 ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(String.valueOf(usernameField.getText));
    user.setPassword(String.valueOf(passwordField.getText));

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            if(e==null){

                Log.i("AppInfo", "SignUp Success");

            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

How would I signup a user with just a username and phone number with verification code?

Comment: Did you google this? You can't be the first one to have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most successful way is to use 3rd party OTP service API. Using this the user registering on your app will receive one time password for number verification. Successful entry will proceed to successful registration.
Steps to got for it:

1. Start leaning how to use OTP for android. [learn more](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP16iD8o3PAhUFlJQKHZPFAI4QFgglMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.simplifiedcoding.net%2Fandroid-sms-verification-app-phone-verification-with-otp%2F&usg=AFQjCNHaIv3USvTHv71Sc-tF3VCAMEezYg&sig2=xUwS9P3ZWsXYv-1dPFho3w)
2. Implement OTP service in your PHP/Java API.